# emacs, auto-complete doesn't suggest anything

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

Hy guys

I finally decided to get into emacs. However setting it up as my C-IDE it encountered difficulty with autocomplete. First of all, here's my .emacs file:

```
; start package.el with emacs
(require 'package)
; add MELPA to repository list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
; initialize package.el
(package-initialize)
; do default config for auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
(set-default 'ac-sources
         '(ac-source-imenu
           ac-source-dictionary
           ac-source-words-in-buffer
           ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers
           ac-source-words-in-all-buffer))
(ac-config-default)
; start yasnippet with emacs
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

The thing is, yasnippet is working fine. When typing in `for` and then pressing TAB will bring up the full for-body and I can go through the different elements by pressing TAB.
But when for example typing `whil` I expected with auto-complete installed, that if I now hit TAB, that there'll be a window coming up with suggestions or it at least starts to auto-complete, but this isn't the case. When typed in `whil` and then pressing TAB nothing happens, and after quickly typing twice it indents the line my cursor is on by a tab.

What's going wrong here? How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I had old popup packages installed; after updating all of my packages it works.